# stretch the edges of any image data areas in python-opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to stretch the edges of the image (duplicate pixels) around data (not transparent) areas in picture.

for example:

**before:**
[image: before]

**after - the red line is only for you to see the difference**
[image: after: (the red line is only for you to see the difference)]

**note:** it's important not to change the dimension of the image, i'ts being used for geographical needs.

I would like to hear any ideas or suggestions from you, code snippets will be welcomed.

thank you!

Comment: I think that the topic You have in mind is called image inpainting. You can find very short and dense overview on that in [Computer Vision Richard Szeliski's book](https://szeliski.org/Book/). It contains only historical overview, but You'll find about 25 sources for all kinds of algorithms that can be used for that. I believe it's in the 10.5.1 section.

Comment: hey, I indeed thought about inpainting, but the algorithms I try to use were very very slow  because I am dealing with very large images.
I will look at the source you send, but if you have a recommendation to a specific algorithm I would like to hear about it. thanks

Comment: You could use [copyMakeBorder](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html). You would have to copy your image, rotate & crop, apply `copyMakeBorder` using `BORDER_REPLICATE` and finally rotate your image back to the original orientation & put it back. No idea about speed comparison to inpainting.

Comment: tnx.
I also thought about using copyMakeBorder but from what I saw it only works on the actual borders of the image and not only on the data areas (like in my example).
please correct me if that is also possible.

Comment: The rotation makes the problem difficult. Do you have access to the image before rotation (do you have the unrotated image and a transformation matrix)? It' possible to find the corners, transform to a rectangle, replicate the borders, transform back, and apply mask for keeping the original pixels with the rotated replicated borders... but it would be much easier if we have the unrotated image.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called image outpainting and You can see very advanced deep learning based solutions in papers on [paperswithcode.com](https://paperswithcode.com/). Current state-of-art is given by Basile Van Hoorick in work [Image Outpainting and Harmonization using Generative Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10960v2.pdf). Code with possibility of usage is placed in his [github profile](https://github.com/basilevh/image-outpainting). See *Usage* section on github to know how to use it.

There are 3 models available to use in *Pretrained models* section:

- G_art.pt: Artistic
- G_nat.pt: Natural
- G_rec.pt: Reconstruction loss only (no adversarial loss)

I believe You'll have to use transfer learning to train and use this architecture in Your use case.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that looks like a very interesting topic I never heard of. however I think you misunderstood me, you made the problem what complicated than what it is.
I don't need to 'guess' the rest of the image, I only need paint it with legit data that exists on the source image, something like the copyMakeBorder mentioned above, only that overcomes the regarding problem I replied about.

Comment: My bad, tell me if I should delete this answer.